# $? from bash script command executed by TCL (open pipe) on windows returns wrong value

Tags: windows, bash, pipe, tcl, tclsh

I've got tcl script with two ways of execution bash script:

```
#exec bash ./run.sh
open "|bash ./run.sh r"
```

The bash script is shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Status failed!" > status
else
    echo "Everything is OK!" > status
fi
```

I'm using tclsh for Windows with bash from git bash. When I use:

`exec bash ./run.sh`

I've got in status file:

> Everything is OK!

otherwise:

`open "|bash ./run.sh r"`

got:

> ERROR: Status failed!

Is there any possibility to correctly detect exit code when opened the tcl pipe?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Shouldn't the `open` call look like so: `open "|bash ./run.sh" r` (`r` outside of the pipe argument)?

Comment: Glenn, did you try this on Windows?  mrcalvin, it does not change anything - same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't describe whether you get different results out of the `ls` part of the script. That matters; the `ls` command is most certainly capable of changing its behaviour according to the environment in which it is invoked. This matters because Tcl executes subprocesses (on Windows) *directly* using the `CreateProcess()` system call, rather than the various wrapped versions that Cygwin and git bash use. Other possibilities are that you're launching the script in a different directory and so on.

However, in general we'd expect a script to behave very similarly when launched via `exec` or via `open |… r` as they share a common core of functionality. The only differences are to do with how output and termination are waited for.

---

If you create a subprocess pipeline, by default you won't get to find out about errors from it until you `close` the pipeline. `exec` generates any errors “immediately” because it doesn't return control to you until the subprocess has terminated and all output has been read.

Comment: Execute ./run.sh from CygWin or GitBash return list of directory and then command `echo $?` returns 0.

The problem exists for such command like: pwd, echo, grep etc. However, redirect these commands (`ls > ls.file`) to file will create status file with: "Everything is OK!" Same if I commented out these command.